# Issue Collecting Static Files in my Heroku app using Django

Tags: django, heroku, static, static-libraries, static-files

Here are my Static Files in 'Settings.py':

```
      STATIC_URL = '/static/'
      STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

      MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
      MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

      STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

      django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

When I run 'heroku run python manage.py collectstatic'

I get '0 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 153 unmodified, 355 post-processed

and I clearly have files in the static folder that need to get collected.
It works just fine locally.  am I missing something dumb?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has a feature to enable auto static files collection. You can use:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0
```

Comment: I thought collectstatic was the default set.  I didn't disable it in the first place.  I still tried this and still got 0 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 153 unmodified, 355 post-processed even though there are static files added.  I'm going to do this app over and retrace my steps.